# waitpid not returning after child has exited

Tags: c, wait

Using a fairly standard fork process:

```
int   pipe_to_child[2];
int   pipe_from_child[2];
int   child_exit_status = -1;

pid_t child_pid = fork();
if (child_pid == 0) {
    close(pipe_from_child[0]); // close their read end
    close(pipe_to_child[1]); // Close their write end
    dup2(pipe_to_child[0], STDIN_FILENO); // Tie the in pipe to stdin
    dup2(pipe_from_child[1], STDOUT_FILENO); // Tie stdout to the out pipe
    // Run the child process
    execve(file_to_run, argv_for_prog, env_for_prog);
}
else {
    close(pipe_from_child[1]); // close their write end
    close(pipe_to_child[0]); // Close their read end
    if (input_to_prog != NULL) write(pipe_to_child[1], input_to_prog, strlen(input_to_prog)); // Send the stdin stuff
    close(pipe_to_child[1]); // Done so send EOF

    // Wait for the child to end
    waitpid(child_pid, &child_exit_status, 0);

    // Do post end-of-child stuff
}
```

This generally works as expected.

However, when the child process, a shell script, sets a further process off in the background. Even though the child process then exits (and is no longer listed by `ps`), the waitpid doesn't return.

The script is this case is meant to start inadyn-mt (a DDNS updater) running in the background.

```
#!/bin/sh
inadyn-mt --background
```

(If I put an & after inadyn-mt it makes no difference)

Comment: has the third process ended when you expect `waitpid(child_pid)` to return?

Comment: Does `execve` return?

Comment: What OS are you running this on?

Comment: @MarcusMüller No, I would like the third prcoess to carry on running in the background after the child (and parent) have completed)

Comment: @EdHeal No, it sets the child running just fine and doesn't return. I know this as the third process starts and is sitting nicely in the ps list.

Comment: @NeilTownsend - Ok. But should put a check in nevertheless or just report an error and exit

Comment: @JohnZwinck Linux 2.6 (fairly minimalist busybox version)

Comment: @EdHeal Agreed - there is in the actual code, I just trimmed the code for the question down to the core.

Comment: @NeilTownsend It's not clear from the code example whether or not you actually  have a `do ... while` loop checking the status set by `waitpid`. Please post a MCVE.

Comment: @user6292850 There isn't a do while around the waitpid as it is a blocking call. The issue here is that it is blocking when I would have expected it to return, not how the return from waitpid is handled.

Comment: Code updated to include what is done with pipes and a sample child.

Comment: @NeilTownsend: MCVE means a **complete** example that someone could compile and run.  As you can tell by the lack of answers, people aren't having much luck guessing the problem from staring at the code you've provided.  Being able to actually test it is much more likely to yield insight.

Comment: @NateEldredge Fair point. I am working on one that is complete, and reasonable. In fact, the code in the question is complete, but it requires you to compile and configure inadyn-mt, which I realise is a big ask. If I can hone it more I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the issue is that the pipes don't get closed. Although the child process exits fine, because it has spawned a further process, this process (even though it doesn't want them) is tied to the pipes to the child's stdin and stdout. The solution I used was to not set up the pipes when I was going to spin off a child from the child.